# Installing mongrel for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I'm trying to install mongrel et al. based on the tutorial here http://blog.codahale.com/2006/06/19/time-for-a-grown-up-server-rails-mongrel-apache-capistrano-and-you/

However, when I try to run

```
sudo gem install daemons gem_plugin mongrel mongrel_cluster --include-dependencies
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:48: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
Expected Ruby Version >= 1.8.7, is 1.8.5
```

I find this slightly odd, as I have previously installed Ruby 1.9.3 (as shown above) with RVM and set it to default with

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

I'm using CentOS 5.8.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the pre release version of mongrel:

```
sudo gem install mongrel --pre
```